# Pentaho BI data source for custom OLAP (XML/A) provider

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, xmla, olap4j

I need to be able to create simple ad-hoc reports on Pentaho BI using plugins like Pivot4j or Saiku. My data provider is SAP with XML/A interface. So the question is how could I create an OLAP data source that based on XMLA protocol? Or it is possible through Mondrian only?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can convert your data from SAP to any rdbms database and then you can use that database as a source in Pentaho Schema workbench and create OLAP Cube.